# c++ this parameter through System::Threading:ThreadStart to class member function

Tags: multithreading, winforms, oop, c++-cli

I'm writing in c++ a graphic user interfaced program and I need to create a threads in the program.
so I'm using `System::Threading` namespace to get my goal.

The function that I want to use as thread is a class member function, so here is what I've done:

```
Server::Server() // constructor
{
    System::Threading::Thread^ T = gcnew System::Threading::Thread(gcnew System::Threading::ThreadStart(this, this->RunServer)); // Server::RunServer
    T->Start();
}
```

since it gave me those errors:

> Error 2   error C3350: 'System::Threading::ThreadStart' : a delegate
>   constructor expects 2 argument(s)
>
> Error 1   error C3867: 'Server::RunServer': function call missing
>   argument list; use '&Server::RunServer' to create a pointer to
>   member

I tried this call:

```
Server::Server() // constructor
{
    System::Threading::Thread^ T = gcnew System::Threading::Thread(gcnew System::Threading::ThreadStart(&Server::RunServer));
    T->Start();
}
```

and received this errors:

> Error 1   error C3364: 'System::Threading::ThreadStart' : invalid
>   argument for delegate constructor; delegate target needs to be a
>   pointer to a member
>   function
>
> 2   IntelliSense: invalid delegate initializer -- function is not a
>   member of a managed
>   class

as far as I know the second try did not succeed because `Server::RunServer` doesn't have address, so it's like to do `&1`.

by the way I tried to use the `ThreadStart` to create thread of none class memeber function and it worked fine.

I'm using win7 - visual studio 2012. How to make it work?

EDIT:
Server declaration:

```
class Server
{
public:

    /* Fields */
    std::string Port;
    std::string Host;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int ListenResult;
    SOCKET ListenSocket;
    SOCKET* ClientSocket;
    SOCKADDR_IN* ADDR;
    int ADDRSize;
    struct addrinfo *result;
    struct addrinfo hints;
    std::vector<Client> Clients;

    /* Methods */
    Server();
    std::wstring StringW(char* String);
    void Print(std::wstring String);
    std::wstring CurrentTime();
    void ParseServerIni();
    void RunServer();
    void PartToString(Part* _Part);
    void InsertListItem(std::string String);
    void ClientHandler(SOCKET* _Sock, SOCKADDR_IN* _ADDR);
    int ParsePacket(Packet &_Packet, int _Bytes, Byte** _PacketBlock);

};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost got the syntax right.

Assuming the declaration is:

```
public ref class Server
{
    void RunServer();
};
```

Then you should combine your two approaches, by specifying both the object to invoke the method on, and the address of the method, with the name of the declaring class.

```
gcnew System::Threading::ThreadStart(this, &Server::RunServer)
```

Comment: the ref attribute is new to me, and now I see that I'll have to change all of my class variables to pointers. I'll try.

Comment: Worked. took me a while to change the whole variables and objects to pointers.